# Why Bottom navigation is shifting, when I am tapping it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

Why Bottom navigation is shifting, when I tap on Button, which takes place on Bottom Navigation.[image: gif showing what happens]

> This is my code:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.diary_button:
                        Fragment diaryfragment = new DiaryFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction ft1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft1.replace(R.id.content_frame, diaryfragment);
                        ft1.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                        ft1.addToBackStack(null);
                        ft1.commit();
                        break;
                      ........
}
}
```

Comment: can you add your activity code with layout?